# How to set timeout for specific executions in PHP?

Tags: php

What I am trying to do is, I am running queries against Twitter and if the deliver of the result delays more than a specific time, than I want to say to user that "Please try again later, timeout." I am not asking the Twitter part, I told my story because of the initial explanation but I like to learn how to accomplish it with mostly PHP native codes.

What's in my mind would be something below:

```
startTimeout(callback(),3000);//Probably this function needs to start a new thread or another concurrent execution scope
//... initiating some twitter queries here

function callback()
{
   echo "Time out, sorry";
}
```

Comment: PHP has no native way of interrupting a function call. Some modules have their own timeout functionality (e.g. curl, sockets), but in general you can NOT interrupt a call in progress, except via the global set_time_limit script killer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set_time_limit() should do the trick. This defines the number of seconds that the script can run.

Comment: How to apply this function to specific executions? Instead of whole application?

Comment: You can apply this to functions, because it sets the script timeout when the script is run. You can run it multiple times as well.

Answer (score 0):

For your purpose, if you use CURL, try

```
$timeout = 10;
curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
```

for other functionality, it's not so easy to accomplish this.

There are function which already support TIMEOUT parameter, it depends on your purpose

Comment: I am not using Curl in this case. Any other recommendation within PHP?

Comment: @Braveyard: just use that curl_setopt for CURL. There's no reliable way to do something like timeout, as PHP is not async as javascript